# Прерывания во время ШИМа

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, stm32, прерывания

Необходимо производить измерения во время ШИМа на МК STM32 Без подачи внешнего напряжения на МК. Только не знаю как сделать это правильно. Первый вариант выключать ШИМ и производить измерения, второй производить измерения в момент "скважин"(под скважиной подразумеваю выключенное состояние) ШИМа. Второй вариант кажется более современным, но возникают определенные трудности:
1) Как определить эту "скважину"?
2) Что если "скважина" длится слишком короткое время и не позволяет выполнить корректное измерение?

И еще если не сложно привести код прерывания, буду очень благодарен.

P.S Частоту можно подобрать более подходящую для данной задачи, она не принципиальна(думаю вполне удачный диапазон 50-150кГц). А скважность ШИМа где то от 0 до 95%

Comment: Ваша задача не реализуема при определенных условиях. (При определенных значениях скважности и частоты). Не хватает данных для ее решения. Дайте частоты и скважности.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич дополнил вопрос

Comment: Не понял, что значит "измерения во время ШИМа". Другое устройство генерирует ШИМ-сигнал, а контроллер его измеряет? Тогда можно использовать таймер в режиме InputCapture. В нём можно задать свои делители и фронт выборки.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич контроллер его генерирует и измеряет, но нкжно подобрать момент периода, когда в шиме "дыра", что бы измерить ЭДС на моторе.

Comment: @Denisok я бы прислушался на Вашем месте к тому, что написал  maestro